# Weird bug navigating multiline command history in pry

Tags: ruby, pry

When I enter a string that is too long for the console width into a pry or regular irb console it wraps as usual, see below (Using pry in OS X 10.8.2 terminal.app):

[image: pry - entering ok]

However when I try to replay the command using the up arrow I get this:
[image]
Pry cuts off some of the command and repeats the prompt. Irb on the other hand behaves just fine, even scrolling up the buffer if needed:
[image: irb - ok replay]

Answer (score 2):

Kyrylo: We have that fixed in the master branch if you `Pry.auto_resize!`

But the problem here is (as ryanf points out on Freenode #pry), is that the prompt has color escapes in it.

`\e[XXn` takes up no spaces, but counts as 5 bytes, so Readline gets confused.

Does anyone know of any Ruby use of Readline that doesn't have this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you resized your terminal window after you entered the first expression. For the time being, Pry doesn't really take into account this event and treats window size as a constant value. Unfortunately, the only solution is to relaunch Pry every time you need to resize your window. This is a bug and sooner or later it will be fixed.

Comment: I didn't resize my terminal window after starting pry but I think @rking is onto something